# Image preview in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, amazon-s3

I am using Angular js(ng-src) to show thumbnail after uploading of image.
On server side I am pre processing Image and then uploading to S3 which is taking few second.So In that case to view the thumbnail i need to refresh my page(without refresh its showing broken image because at that time image is not available in S3).

Is there any way In angular I can load Image when it is available in S3 after some time.

Comment: Have you tried using a promise in your http call?

Comment: @A.Alger actually i am using node to upload the image to s3..but for pre processing it is throwing to Queue from where Java take it minified it and send back to S3.